# receiving intent from other app causing force close

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create a application for android in which I want to allow user to share **text** using my application.

The code that I have is as follow. Please help me find the error.

I don't have logcat message because whenever I ran the sharer application in emulator and clicked on share button it directly opened the stock message application, despite my other application being installed in the emulator, so I had to test the application on my phone.

**CODE OF APPLICATION I CREATED FOR SHARING**

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

**MAIN APPLICATION**

**MANIFEST DECLARATION**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**CODE FROM MAINACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
Intent myintent = getIntent();
String action = myintent.getAction();
String type = myintent.getType();

if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type !=null) {
    if("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(myintent);
  }
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        editText.setText(sharedText);
    }
}
```

Please help me find the error why there no Intent Chooser pop up with my application and the stock message application.

Comment: The fact you're running the app on the phone does not stop you seeing logcat?  I assume that you are running it from your IDE.

Comment: @Simon not from the IDE. i am copying the `apk` file to my phone , then installing it on the phone and running the application.

Comment: Even so, connect the device to your PC and you can use DDMS to see the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run it in emulator and use debugger to find where your app is crashed then write it here  try use catching exceptions